# WP7.1:Tap event fires on 7.1 & 8 emulators but not on device

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a logo image that I created Tap and DoubleTap events for.
Works fine on the 7.1 and the 8 emulators.
Doesn't fire at all on my Lumia 920.
Other touch events work fine.
Any idea on what I am missing?

Never mind.
I had to uninstall the app from the phone and redeploy, then it worked fine.
Partial redeploy partially failed, without any error messages.

Comment: Post the solution as answer the guidelines suggest to make self answered questions when you already know the solution, but you must write the issue as a question and answer properly, or delete the question

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Rick Hantz:
Never mind.
I had to uninstall the app from the phone and redeploy, then it worked fine.
Partial redeploy partially failed, without any error messages.